# Get filtered data from Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following method for displaying 8 latest posts in the app. User will press `Show more` button and other 8 posts will be displayed. I am trying to add a filter to search by specific fields of the post, and expect the results to be paginated as well. The problem is that I am stuck how to use the query created to get those specific posts and if the user clicks back or cancels filter how to retrieve the latest posts again. I would appreciate if someone could explain how should I get this done.

```
  const getPosts = async () => {
    let docs;
    let postsReference = firebase.firestore().collection("products").orderBy("createdAt").limit(8);
    
    await postsReference
    .get()
    .then(documentSnapshot => {
      docs = documentSnapshot;
      lastVisible = documentSnapshot.docs[documentSnapshot.docs.length - 1];
      console.log("last", lastVisible);
    });

    docs["docs"].forEach(doc => {
      postsArray.push(doc.data());
    });

    postsArray.forEach(function (post) {
      createPost(post);
    })
  }

    const paginate = async () => {
      let docs;
      let postsReference = 
      firebase.firestore().collection("products").orderBy("createdAt").startAfter(lastVisible).limit(8);
      console.log(postsReference);

      await postsReference
      .get()
      .then(documentSnapshot => {
        docs = documentSnapshot;
        console.log(docs);
        lastVisible = documentSnapshot.docs[documentSnapshot.docs.length - 1];
      });

      docs["docs"].forEach(doc => {
        createPost(doc.data());
        postsSize++;
      });
    }
    
    if (showMoreButton != null) {
      showMoreButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        paginate();
      });
    }
```

```
applyFilterButton.addEventListener("click", async function () {
  
  ....

  let filterQuery = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("products")
    .where("productType", "==", productTypeOption)
    .where("productLocation", "==", productLocationOption);
  if (productPriceOption == "high") {
    filterQuery = filterQuery.orderBy("price", "desc");
  } else {
    filterQuery = filterQuery.orderBy("price");
  }
  
  await filterQuery
  .get()
  .then(function (querySnapshot) {
    console.log(querySnapshot.docs);
    
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
      // Does not print to console 
      console.log("Inside querySnapshot");

      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: To confirm the question, you have a search feature with filters and pagination. You want to know how to request the previous 8 records or how to search again removing the filters. Is that right?

Comment: If you wanted to go back to the previous elements you should keep track of all the documents that allow you to search for the following 8 ones. If you wanted to reset the search just use `addEventListener` to your "go back" button that performs the original search and posts it using your method `createPost`.

Comment: @Ajordat thank you for your answer, I understand  and I will use your suggestion. The question has 2 parts, one that you answered with going back and another is how to actually get the filtered data from firestore. In the last lines of code I query the data and when I try to get it from db, it does not console log anything. It does not reach the ```forEach``` method...  I have this custom index.

Comment: Maybe it could be worth to use the `await` keyword when calling the `get` method. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Ajordat I have tried it now and still do not get anything in the console.

Comment: Please update the code on the question.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't print anything inside the `forEach` loop because it doesn't retrieve anything, not because that part isn't reached. Add a `console.log` statement before the `forEach`, inside the `then` function. Update the code on the question. Does it output anything?

Comment: @Ajordat I have added the ```console.log``` there. It looks like it returns an empty array every time a filter something. I tried different combinations by fields and still returns an empty array. Does it mean there must be something wrong with the query?

Comment: What does it show if you use no `where` conditions? Does it retrieve all the documents in the `products` collection?

Comment: @Ajordat I have commented both ```where``` conditions, and it does ```console.log``` all documents in  the ```products```.

Comment: Then the problem is with the `where` conditions. Print the values of `productTypeOption` and `productLocationOption` and check from the Console whether you have any values that match both conditions. You shouldn't because they would've been returned.

Comment: @Ajordat I figured it out, turns out I was saving the fields in document as ```type``` and ```location``` instead of ```productType``` and ```productLocation``` as I was searching in queries, lol. Thank you very much for assisting and helping debugging!

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to post yourself an answer explaining the issue and how you have solved it. You can then accept it so other people can find this question more easily.